# flutter: library not found for -lBoringSSL-GRPC

Tags: xcode, flutter, release, ios14, runner

trying to build my flutter app from XCode 12 Runner.xcworkspace on my iphone 11 iOS-14 as release, i have the latest flutter version 1.22.0 and it gives me this error.. here's my log

```
Ld /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hbcmigkttdicebgubholcezdusdf/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/Tamata.app/Tamata normal (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
    cd /Users/admin/AndroidStudioProjects/tamatafreshiq/ios
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -target arm64-apple-ios12.0 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS14.0.sdk -L/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hbcmigkttdicebgubholcezdusdf/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos -L/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hbcmigkttdicebgubholcezdusdf/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/BoringSSL-GRPC -L/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hbcmigkttdicebgubholcezdusdf/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/FMDB -L/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hbcmigkttdicebgubholcezdusdf/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/FirebaseAuth -L/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hbcmigkttdicebgubholcezdusdf/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/FirebaseCore -L/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hbcmigkttdicebgubholcezdusdf/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/FirebaseCoreDiagnostics -L/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hbcmigkttdicebgubholcezdusdf/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/FirebaseFirestore -L/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hbcmigkttdicebgubholcezdusdf/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/FirebaseInstallations -L/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hbcmigkttdicebgubholcezdusdf/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/FirebaseInstanceID -L/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hbcmigkttdicebgubholcezdusdf/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/FirebaseMessaging -L/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hbcmigkttdicebgubholcezdusdf/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/FirebaseStorage -L/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hbcmigkttdicebgubholcezdusdf/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/GTMSessionFetcher -L/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hbcmigkttdicebgubholcezdusdf/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/GoogleDataTransport -L/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hbcmigkttdicebgubholcezdusdf/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/GoogleUtilities -L/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hbcmigkttdicebgubholcezdusdf/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/PromisesObjC -L/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hbcmigkttdicebgubholcezdusdf/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/Protobuf -L/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hbcmigkttdicebgubholcezdusdf/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/TOCropViewController -L/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hbcmigkttdicebgubholcezdusdf/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/abseil -L/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hbcmigkttdicebgubholcezdusdf/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/cloud_firestore -L/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hbcmigkttdicebgubholcezdusdf/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/firebase_auth -L/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hbcmigkttdicebgubholcezdusdf/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/firebase_core -L/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hbcmigkttdicebgubholcezdusdf/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/firebase_messaging -L/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hbcmigkttdicebgubholcezdusdf/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/firebase_storage -L/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hbcmigkttdicebgubholcezdusdf/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/gRPC-C++ -L/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hbcmigkttdicebgubholcezdusdf/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/gRPC-Core -L/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hbcmigkttdicebgubholcezdusdf/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/image_cropper -L/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hbcmigkttdicebgubholcezdusdf/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/image_picker -L/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hbcmigkttdicebgubholcezdusdf/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/leveldb-library -L/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hbcmigkttdicebgubholcezdusdf/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/nanopb -L/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hbcmigkttdicebgubholcezdusdf/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/path_provider -L/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hbcmigkttdicebgubholcezdusdf/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/shared_preferences -L/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hbcmigkttdicebgubholcezdusdf/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/sqflite -L/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hbcmigkttdicebgubholcezdusdf/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/url_launcher -L/Users/admin/AndroidStudioProjects/tamatafreshiq/ios/Flutter -F/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hbcmigkttdicebgubholcezdusdf/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos -F/Users/admin/AndroidStudioProjects/tamatafreshiq/ios/Pods/../Flutter -F/Users/admin/AndroidStudioProjects/tamatafreshiq/ios/Pods/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks -F/Users/admin/AndroidStudioProjects/tamatafreshiq/ios/Pods/GoogleAppMeasurement/Frameworks -F/Users/admin/AndroidStudioProjects/tamatafreshiq/ios/Flutter -filelist /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hbcmigkttdicebgubholcezdusdf/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Release-iphoneos/Runner.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Tamata.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @loader_path/Frameworks -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -dead_strip -Xlinker -object_path_lto -Xlinker /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hbcmigkttdicebgubholcezdusdf/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Release-iphoneos/Runner.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Tamata_lto.o -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -ObjC -lBoringSSL-GRPC -lFMDB -lFirebaseAuth -lFirebaseCore -lFirebaseCoreDiagnostics -lFirebaseFirestore -lFirebaseInstallations -lFirebaseInstanceID -lFirebaseMessaging -lFirebaseStorage -lGTMSessionFetcher -lGoogleDataTransport -lGoogleUtilities -lPromisesObjC -lProtobuf -lTOCropViewController -labseil -lc++ -lcloud_firestore -lfirebase_auth -lfirebase_core -lfirebase_messaging -lfirebase_storage -lgRPC-C++ -lgRPC-Core -limage_cropper -limage_picker -lleveldb-library -lnanopb -lpath_provider -lshared_preferences -lsqflite -lsqlite3 -lurl_launcher -lz -framework CoreTelephony -framework FIRAnalyticsConnector -framework FirebaseAnalytics -framework Flutter -framework Foundation -framework GoogleAppMeasurement -framework MobileCoreServices -framework SafariServices -framework Security -framework StoreKit -framework SystemConfiguration -framework UIKit -weak_framework UserNotifications -framework Flutter -lPods-Runner -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hbcmigkttdicebgubholcezdusdf/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Release-iphoneos/Runner.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Tamata_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hbcmigkttdicebgubholcezdusdf/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/Tamata.app/Tamata

ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hbcmigkttdicebgubholcezdusdf/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/BoringSSL-GRPC'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hbcmigkttdicebgubholcezdusdf/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/FMDB'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hbcmigkttdicebgubholcezdusdf/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/FirebaseAuth'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hbcmigkttdicebgubholcezdusdf/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/FirebaseCore'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hbcmigkttdicebgubholcezdusdf/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/FirebaseCoreDiagnostics'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hbcmigkttdicebgubholcezdusdf/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/FirebaseFirestore'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hbcmigkttdicebgubholcezdusdf/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/FirebaseInstallations'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hbcmigkttdicebgubholcezdusdf/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/FirebaseInstanceID'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hbcmigkttdicebgubholcezdusdf/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/FirebaseMessaging'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hbcmigkttdicebgubholcezdusdf/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/FirebaseStorage'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hbcmigkttdicebgubholcezdusdf/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/GTMSessionFetcher'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hbcmigkttdicebgubholcezdusdf/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/GoogleDataTransport'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hbcmigkttdicebgubholcezdusdf/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/GoogleUtilities'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hbcmigkttdicebgubholcezdusdf/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/PromisesObjC'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hbcmigkttdicebgubholcezdusdf/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/Protobuf'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hbcmigkttdicebgubholcezdusdf/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/TOCropViewController'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hbcmigkttdicebgubholcezdusdf/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/abseil'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hbcmigkttdicebgubholcezdusdf/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/cloud_firestore'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hbcmigkttdicebgubholcezdusdf/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/firebase_auth'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hbcmigkttdicebgubholcezdusdf/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/firebase_core'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hbcmigkttdicebgubholcezdusdf/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/firebase_messaging'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hbcmigkttdicebgubholcezdusdf/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/firebase_storage'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hbcmigkttdicebgubholcezdusdf/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/gRPC-C++'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hbcmigkttdicebgubholcezdusdf/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/gRPC-Core'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hbcmigkttdicebgubholcezdusdf/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/image_cropper'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hbcmigkttdicebgubholcezdusdf/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/image_picker'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hbcmigkttdicebgubholcezdusdf/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/leveldb-library'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hbcmigkttdicebgubholcezdusdf/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/nanopb'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hbcmigkttdicebgubholcezdusdf/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/path_provider'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hbcmigkttdicebgubholcezdusdf/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/shared_preferences'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hbcmigkttdicebgubholcezdusdf/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/sqflite'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hbcmigkttdicebgubholcezdusdf/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/url_launcher'
ld: library not found for -lBoringSSL-GRPC
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: I am seeing the same issue with `ld: warning directory not found for option -L...`, the first one being for Mantle, and after those warnings I get `ld: library not found for -lMantle`.

Comment: I was building release on a simulator thats why, forgot to switch to my phone.

Comment: Okay, I noticed that XCode can build, but not for the simulator on release, as you said. However, `flutter build` seems to be unable to build anything (release, debug, sim, phone) with exactly the same error.